# Laravel 5.1 Update message but it touch both created_at and updated_at

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

As title, after update message using code below:

```
$id = 1;
$message ="Updated";
Post::where(['id' => $id])->update(['message' => $message]);
```

both **created_at** and **updated_at** change to current timestamp.

how to make it update timestamp only updated_at and dont update timestamp at created_at when using update?

Thanks

Comment: What migration did you use to create the created_at and updated_at columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **created_at** column is probably set to be [auto-updated](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Comment: Hi @Adrien Neveu
thanks for your info. 
I just disable the on updating timestamp and it work. 
Thanks